# Update style on element when ValidationError has occured, with an overriden template

Tags: wpf, xaml

I've overriden the `Template` of `TextBox` to give it a rounded border:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="b:TextBoxBehaviours.SelectAllTextOnFocus" Value="True" />
    <Setter Property="Width" Value="75" />
    <Setter Property="Margin" Value="2" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Border x:Name="brdTxtBx" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="3" BorderBrush="{x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrush}">
                    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
                </Border>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

What I'm trying to achieve is that when the `TextBox` gets a validation error, the `Border` should change colour to a different one (e.g. Red). I've tried putting a `DataTrigger` in the `Border` style, but that doesn't seem to work.

```
<Border x:Name="brdTxtBx" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="3" BorderBrush="{x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrush}">
    <Border.Style>
        <Style TargetType="Border">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType=TextBox}, Path=Validaton.HasError}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Border.Style>
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
</Border>
```

I've tried changing the `Mode` on the binding to see if that works, but doesn't seem to have any affect. I've also changed the `DataBinding` path to bind to another property (i.e. the `Text` value), to see if that triggers it, so I think it's more my understanding of `DataTrigger`s in `ControlTemplate`s isn't quite right?

Am I approaching this incorrectly, or just slightly off?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `ControlTemplate.Triggers` section to change properties of elements inside the template dynamically. Use `Setter.TargetName` to specifiy the named element to target:

```
<ControlTemplate>
  <Border x:Name="brdTxtBx" BorderThickness="2" CornerRadius="3"
     BorderBrush="{x:Static SystemColors.ActiveBorderBrush}">
    <ScrollViewer x:Name="PART_ContentHost" />
  </Border>
  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
      <Setter TargetName="brdTxtBx" Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
    </Trigger>
  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

The usual way to achieve your requirements is to use the [`Validation.ErrorTemplate` Attached Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validation.errortemplate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx). From the linked page on MSDN:

> If the user enters an invalid value, you may want to provide some feedback about the error on the application user interface (UI). One way to provide such feedback is to set the Validation.ErrorTemplate attached property to a custom ControlTemplate.

```
<TextBox Name="textBox1" Width="50" FontSize="15"
     Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource validationTemplate}"
     Style="{StaticResource textBoxInError}"
     Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Margin="2">

...
```

Again, from the linked page:

> The following example shows the custom ControlTemplate validationTemplate that creates a red exclamation mark to notify the user of a validation error. Control templates are used to redefine the appearance of a control:

```
<ControlTemplate x:Key="validationTemplate">
  <DockPanel>
    <TextBlock Foreground="Red" FontSize="20">!</TextBlock>
    <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
  </DockPanel>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Please see the linked page for more information.